# Access Class Instance Props in React Component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, web

I have a class that only returns the children only

```
class Name extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.text = "meow";
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

And I created the Component in my JSX with text saying my Classes Prop "text"

```
<Name>
  <Text>{Name.text}</Text>
</Name>
```

But it errors saying that Name.text doesn't exist, Did you mean to access a static property?

How do I use the JSX tag just to do `new Name()` then access the info inside using React/React Native?

**Edit 1** Better Example

```
interface User {
  data: object;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
class User extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props: object) {
    super(props);
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.data);
    this.firstName = this.data.results.name.first;
    this.lastName = this.data.results.name.last;
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

```
<User>
  <Text>{User.firstName}</Text>
</User>
```

Comment: Are you sure a component is the right tool for you? You don't seem to be using any of the things that components provide.

Comment: Yes, I'm using React Native so I don't really have a choice but I'm doing it this way so anything that needs to use that info will be placed under the Tag <Name>

Comment: @NicholasTower I edited the post with a better Example of what my class would look like And withing the <User id="userID"> Tag you could call User.firstName etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `User` component to have the logic for figuring out the first name and last name, but you want the parent component to decide what to do with those values, then I'd recommend using a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). This lets you pass a function to `Name`, telling it what you would like to render.

Here's an example passing the function as the `children` prop (though you could use a different prop if you prefer):

```
class User extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  }
  constructor(props: object) {
    super(props);
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ 
          firstName: data.results.name.first, 
          lastName: data.results.name.last,
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName);
  }
}

// used like:

<User>
  {(firstName, lastName) => (
    <Text>{firstName}</Text>
  )}
</User>
```